# How to convert string to float fast

Tags: python, performance, csv, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a huge dataset that is organized into a 2-Dimensional array of strings that I am converting to floats. I currently am performing this operation using nested loops and python's `float()` function, but I am receiving the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'slow'`.

Other answers related to this question recommend `maps()`, which I tried, but I cannot get to work right. Commented out is my attempt. It doesn't throw the 'slow' error but my data does not present correctly in my present configuration. What are some ways to convert a csv of strings to floats fast using my csv parser? I am using my own parser because the csv file I am using has a long complicated header. How to improve performance?

```
    # parse() takes .lvm input as a string and returns a clean 2-D array of data
def parse(self):
    data = self.get_data()
    word = 'Comment'
    start_index = data.find(word) + len(word)
    if start_index != -1:
        data_block = data[start_index:]
        data_list = data_block.split('\n')  # create grid rows
        data_list.pop(0)  # remove first blank value
        data_list.pop(len(data_list) - 1)  # remove last blank value
        for row in range(len(data_list)):
            data_list[row] = data_list[row].split('\t')  # create grid cols
            data_list[row].pop(0)  # remove leading blank values
            for col in range(len(data_list[row])):
                data_list[row][col] = float(data_list[row][col])
                #map(float, data_list)
    return data_list
```

Sample Data:

````
Writer_Version  2
Reader_Version  2
Separator   Tab
Decimal_Separator   .
Multi_Headings  No
X_Columns   No
Time_Pref   Absolute
Operator    bowman-lab
Date    2019/06/12
Time    10:52:28.98046875
***End_of_Header*** 

Channels    17                                                                  
Samples 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
Date    2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  2019/06/17  
Time    00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  00:00:24.056640625  
X_Dimension Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    Time    
X0  0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   0.0000000000000000E+0   
Delta_X 1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    
***End_of_Header***                                                                     
X_Value Untitled    Untitled 1  Untitled 2  Untitled 3  Untitled 4  Untitled 5  Untitled 6  Untitled 7  Untitled 8  Untitled 9  Untitled 10 Untitled 11 Untitled 12 Untitled 13 Untitled 14 Untitled 15 Untitled 16 Comment
    167.999595  20.424800   3.683480E-7 7.250010E-8 4.262870E-8 3.519030E-9 12.113764   20.602297   3.465850E-7 6.558680E-13    5.736950E-13    5.163760E-13    4.677860E-13    4.531120E-13    4.404600E-13    4.197010E-13    4.200990E-13
    168.000278  20.209800   3.682400E-7 7.128310E-8 4.211100E-8 3.579760E-9 11.763638   19.912815   3.499790E-7 6.066650E-13    5.517010E-13    5.219980E-13    4.545310E-13    4.693880E-13    4.422010E-13    4.086500E-13    4.332030E-13
    168.000949  19.994800   3.700140E-7 7.218710E-8 4.114490E-8 3.547610E-9 11.597921   20.348094   3.482310E-7 6.436670E-13    5.749850E-13    4.861690E-13    4.723660E-13    4.492960E-13    4.461890E-13    4.627340E-13    4.153260E-13
    168.001620  20.263500   3.668960E-7 7.258560E-8 4.234280E-8 3.562130E-9 11.886933   20.377022   3.460820E-7 6.091490E-13    5.796400E-13    5.023800E-13    4.766230E-13    4.636040E-13    4.376650E-13    4.207870E-13    4.106500E-13
    168.002303  20.102300   3.676490E-7 7.148780E-8 4.086190E-8 3.593330E-9 11.371597   19.894582   3.484330E-7 6.135020E-13    5.799730E-13    4.974020E-13    4.556280E-13    4.468340E-13    4.787080E-13    4.021570E-13    4.381160E-13
    168.002975  20.048500   3.665200E-7 7.319230E-8 4.065750E-8 3.582310E-9 11.349520   20.431593   3.468890E-7 6.248330E-13    5.571080E-13    4.762140E-13    4.785580E-13    4.804170E-13    4.381590E-13    4.416420E-13    4.154980E-13
    168.003657  20.263500   3.654450E-7 7.281390E-8 4.126510E-8 3.568820E-9 11.562673   20.402794   3.447040E-7 6.328950E-13    5.828000E-13    5.180320E-13    4.820620E-13    4.573160E-13    4.551010E-13    4.197980E-13    4.287960E-13
    168.004329  20.156000   3.663590E-7 7.158880E-8 4.066320E-8 3.596200E-9 11.307269   19.906791   3.475940E-7 6.310140E-13    5.826500E-13    5.099370E-13    4.840400E-13    4.593690E-13    4.370300E-13    4.312680E-13    4.105530E-13
    168.005000  20.048500   3.682940E-7 7.245720E-8 4.078780E-8 3.518080E-9 11.593767   20.595666   3.454440E-7 6.227800E-13    5.723940E-13    5.207940E-13    4.895550E-13    4.598850E-13    4.733010E-13    4.329670E-13    4.348700E-13
    168.005683  20.048500   3.675950E-7 7.206990E-8 4.156710E-8 3.572390E-9 11.635656   20.174141   3.465520E-7 6.309170E-13    5.952270E-13    5.362420E-13    5.016380E-13    4.777300E-13    4.726130E-13    4.423840E-13    4.353530E-13
    168.006354  20.156000   3.697450E-7 7.146210E-8 4.046190E-8 3.593570E-9 11.259527   19.886102   3.479970E-7 6.345190E-13    5.939700E-13    5.047770E-13    4.874590E-13    4.812450E-13    4.645720E-13    4.578530E-13    4.002650E-13```
````

Comment: Can you also add a sample of what your data looks like?

Comment: Also the error. I've never seen an error ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'slow'``` unless slow is a variable

Comment: I'm assuming ```data_list``` is a 2-D array like ```data_list=[['3.5','6.1'],['2.0','33333.99999999']]```, and ```map(float,data_list)``` can not work, argument to ```float``` must be a ```str``` or ```int``` not a ```list```.

Comment: I think that it means that the operation is slow because it is processing multiple files

Comment: @MrBerry I doubt that. According to [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError)  ```ValueError: Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch```

Comment: The parser works perfectly on small batches of data, it only fails with large datasets

Comment: run `float("slow")` and you get the same error - it seams you have string `"slow"` in your data.

Comment: I will look for it

Comment: @Babydesta you were absolutely correct. The word slow was in my data. Thank you. That solves my problem.